# Can I use the finders Item count of a smart folder as a trigger?

Tags: macos, triggers, applescript, finder

I am writing an apple script in osx to copy the unique items from a saved search folder into another folder. I would like the script to run whenever the saved search (property list) returns more or fewer items.

Unfortunately, I haven't as yet, found any way of triggering this script automatically.

While staring at the finder window, I noticed that a saved search folder, displays the number of items within it, at the bottom on the status bar.

[Saved Search Item Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCA4Z.png)

If possible I would like to use this variable, the 'X Items', as a trigger when the number changes but how do I find it?

I have looked through a lot of smart folder queries to no avail. If anyone can shed any light on how Finder manages to calculate the item count of a smart folder and how I might acquire and use it as a trigger would be really appreciated.

Thanks, Craig.

Comment: As you found, a "Smart Folder" is not a folder at all, it is a property list/XML file that contains a Spotlight query and some appearance settings - the Finder just happens to show the result of the search in the same way it shows a folder.  Since it is just a search, the particular items (and count) wouldn't be known until the search is actually performed by the Finder (or some other script or application using the same or similar terms).

Comment: Thank you @red_menace for clarifying. I realised, after your comment, that the act of clicking on the smart folder in finder is the trigger itself. In this moment, it invokes the search and an item count is calculated. I originally thought that spotlight preprocessed the folder counts. I think the only way forward from here is a scheduled trigger.